# Origin of "blimey"

Tags: etymology, slang

According to [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=blimey):

(It is also used in excitement.)

> **blimey**
>
> by 1889, probably a corruption of *(God) blind me!* First attested in a slang dictionary which defines it as "an apparently meaningless, abusive term."

*Etymonline* includes the date of origin as 1889 but doesn't cite the first usage. What slang dictionary it is referring to? Is it possible to find more details and the first usage of the word?

Comment: "blind me" isn't an origin enough for you?

Comment: @Mitch Origin as in where from.

Comment: 'First attested' or the  equivalent is the almost universal accompaniment to any etymology. 'First used by William Chaucer in the Olde Bush at 4:45 pm on the 6th of December 1327' is unlikely. The only exceptions seem to be 'gas', and more recent coinages like David Crystal's 'lexeme'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because if the etymological  information provided by one authority is dismissed as being 'not [giving] the origin', it is 99.98% probable that all other etymologies will not give 'the origin' but rather an earliest found example.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because I edited to make it better and there are good/detailed answers.

Comment: The slang dictionary in question is Charles G. Leland, [_A Dictionary of Slang, Jargon & Cant_](https://books.google.com/books?id=0AoOAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA135&dq=%22an+apparently+meaningless,+abusive+term%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizrdmr3t_JAhUJ32MKHSE4CDwQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22an%20apparently%20meaningless%2C%20abusive%20term%22&f=false) (1889).

Comment: I would say the origin of blimey as an interjection meaning "Oh goodness" is unknown. Explanations such as "God blind/blame me" are not convincing at all.

Comment: @rogermue God blind/blame me is an assumption of where the phrase blimey originated

Comment: @anonymous  Well,  if you are content with that assumption, okay. I'm not content with it.

Comment: @rogermue It says it right in etymonline Here: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=blimey

Comment: @anonymous  Etymonline says "probably", ie the origin is not clear.

Comment: @rogermue Yes, but it is an assumption nevertheless.

Comment: An assumption without any semantic logic is not worth much.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The OED entry goes for either *blind me* or *blame me*.

> Vulgar corruption of the imprecation blind me! or blame me! (blame v.
>   7a). (Cf. gorblimey int.)>
>
> 1889   in A. Barrère & C. G. Leland Dict. Slang   s.v.
>
> 1894   Punch 27 Oct. 193/1   Blymy, you're a knockout!
>
> 1897   W. S. Maugham Liza of Lambeth ix. 153   Bli' me if I know wot
>   yer all talkin' abaht.
>
> 1922   J. Joyce Ulysses ii. xii. [Cyclops] 297   God blimey if she
>   aint a clinker... Blimey it makes me kind of bleeding cry.
>
> 1932   Punch Almanack 1933 7 Nov. [18/1]   ‘Your mentality is
>   erroneous and—er—soggy. Blime! what a cod!’ he concluded.
>
> 1954   ‘R. Crompton’ William & Moon Rocket viii. 235   ‘Blimey!’ said
>   Charlemagne. ‘Pardon him, dear,’ said Miss Milton in a shaking voice.
>   ‘He doesn't often use bad language.’

And for *Gorblimey*

> Vulgar corruption of the imprecation God blind me! See also quots.
>   1919, 1925.>
>
> 1896   A. Morrison Child of Jago i. 16   Gawblimy, not what?
>
> 1909   J. R. Ware Passing Eng.   Gorblimy (about 1875). A gutter
>   phrase.
>
> 1911   L. Stone Jonah i. ix. 105   ‘Gorblimey! A knock-out!’..Stinky,
>   with a haphazard blow, had given Chook the dreaded knock-out.
>
> 1914   T. A. Baggs Back from Front xix. 92   Gor blimey, 'ow are ye,
>   then, old townie?
>
> 1915   A. D. Gillespie Let. 27 Mar. in Lett. from Flanders (1916) 74
>   Most of the infantry now wear the soft ‘Gor'bli'me’ hat which looks
>   horrid, but does not give such a mark as the flat-topped ‘Brodrick’.
>
> 1918   W. J. Locke Rough Road v. 51   ‘Gorblime!’ said Chipmunk,
>   ‘that's the first I 'eard of it.’
>
> 1919   War Terms in Athenæum 8 Aug. 729/1   ‘Gor-blimey’, a soft
>   service cap.
>
> 1925   E. Fraser & J. Gibbons Soldier & Sailor Words   Gorblimey... An
>   exclamation or adjective of emphasis. A ‘Gorblimey’ was the common
>   colloquial term for an unwired, floppy, field-service cap worn by a
>   certain type of subaltern in defiance of the Dress Regulations. Lines
>   from a song, popular before the War, ran:—‘He wears Gorblimey trousers
>   An a little Gorblimey 'at.’
>
> 1956   J. Masters Bugles & Tiger 49   A tweed gorblimey cap worn well
>   forward on the head.
>
> 1958   Oxf. Mag. 27 Feb. 326/1   The British and American tendency is
>   to emphasise the Gorblimey aspect of history, the feelings of the
>   ordinary man on the spot at the time.
>
> 1962   Listener 31 May 967/1   She offered a gorblimey cheerfulness.

Comment: But don't they take pains to point out that the first example they can find in print isn't likely to be the true original?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  I don't think there has ever been any suggestion that the OED's first example could be the original.  For most words they have a prior section on etymology, but in this case no etymology is attempted. .

Comment: @BiscuitBoy Note that it has gone beyond being an imprecation. See such examples as *She offered a gorblimey cheerfulness*.

Comment: But OP discounts one authority on those grounds. (Thus, I'd say he cannot expect an answer that 'tells the origin'.)

Comment: +1 That's for the official source based on research, that we would never have been able to see if you hadn't given it here. Thank you!!.

Comment: So.. the more common version of this for today seems to be "[The *F* word] me", at least in my region - and if the "k" at the end of the first word blended better with "me" it might merge together at some point? Say, "Fume me" > "Fumey!" Etymology is interesting.

Answer (score 8):

This is an example of the so-called subjunctive in English. Such sentences are invocations where the act of saying them is presented as an exhortation that will make them hopefully occur. Here are some similar examples:

- God save the queen.
- Peace be upon you.
- Bless you.
- Praise be.
- Well strike me down with a thunderbolt.
- Heaven forbid.
- So be it.
- (God) damn you.

Sometimes, of course, these sentences don't really convey that we actually do want these things to happen. They  are very often just an expression of surprise:

- Well strike me down with a thunderbolt.
- God blind me.
- Shiver me timbers.

In such sentences we don't really think that the speaker wants to be struck down by a thunderbolt, blinded, or have their boat hit by a cannon so hard that its timbers shivered.

So, as to where *cor blimey* comes from, if it comes from *God blind me*, it would seem to be a relatively transparent saying.

However, the purpose of my post is to show *why* we might have ended up with *cor blimey* from *god blind me*.

First of all, the (admittedly modern) transcription for *God blind me* in RP is:

- gɒd blaɪnd mi

You will notice that there's a /d/ there at the end of the word *blind*. Interestingly, the phoneme /d/ is subject to elision in English if surrounded by consonants and occurring after a voiced consonant. Here it's followed by an /m/ and preceded by a voiced /n/. So in natural speech, this consonant would more often than not be dropped, giving us:

- gɒd blaɪn mi (God bline me)

What we see, after the /d/ has been dropped, is an /n/ followed by an /m/. Now, the phoneme /n/ is also highly unstable in English. It tends to change its place of articulation according to the following consonant. For this reason we see words like *input* being pronounced *imput* and so forth. This is called anticipatory assimilation and in this instance, if people say the phrase above in natural speech, this is going to give us:

- gɒd blaɪm mi (God blime me)

Looking at the word *God*, you will notice that this too ends in a /d/. However, it is not surrounded by consonants. The phoneme /d/ as we have already seen is unstable. When it doesn't disappear, it also likes to change place according to the following consonant. So in natural speech we get things like *bab boy* for *bad boy* or *Rebbridge* for *Redbridge*. Again this is an example of anticipatory assimilation. In our current example this will now give us:

- gɒb blaɪm mi

Because we have a sequence of two /b/s and then two /n/s, each of these double consonant segments are very likely to be interpreted as a single consonant:

- gɒ blaɪmi

Now, if we are interpreting the /b/ as being part of the second word, we are going to interpret the 'O' sound from *god* as being an /ɔ:/ as in THOUGHT, not an /ɒ/ as in LOT. The reason for this is that word final English syllables  are not allowed to end in /ɒ/. The THOUGHT vowel is the nearest allowable vowel to the original LOT vowel that we can use in a word final syllable.

So, there's some phonetic and phonological speculation about why *cor blimey* may be derived from *God blind me*. Of course whether this actually *is* the derivation in the first place, we don't truthfully know.

I am well aware that this does not exactly answer the Original Poster's question - but it was too long to put in the comments!

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive treatment. But I am a little puzzled about your reference to the subjunctive. They are mostly straightforward imperatives aren't they?

Comment: @WS2 'May God blind me' is the subjunctive. 'God blinds me' would be the declarative.

Comment: @Mitch Are you sure it is not an instruction to God of "Blind me"? i.e 'God, please blind me!'. But perhaps not. You may be right. But "Shiver me timbers" must be an imperative, mustn't it?

Comment: @WS2 No, "God save the queen" for example, isn't an imperative: it's not like "WS2, up-vote my answer" it's more like "WS2 upvote my answer". It certainly has a *may* feeling about it, but there's never been a *may* there. That was one of the earlier theories about imperatives and subjunctives - namely that they had an invisible *that* or *should* snuggled in there. Problem that I remember best with that (which isn't meant to be the killer reason why not) is that they seemed to pre-date some of those modals, if my memory serves me correctly - which it may not do!

Comment: I edited the question to make it better and your answer is more relevant now also. I would rather save the question because there are good answers and the OP showed some research effort.